# Search in query

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any solutions out there, that make it possible to search in a query.

Example:

I've this simple query:

```
$this->db->where('start >=',time());
$this->db->where('end <=',strtotime("+1 month"));
$result = $this->db->get('bookings');
```

What I then want it to be able to make a search that looks like my query above, but which doesn't search in the database, but in the $result results.

So it should be possible to do something like:

```
$where = array(
  'start >=' => time(),
  'end <=' => strtotime("+1 day")
);
$get_result_info_by_search = $this->Search_model->get_stored_results($result, $where);
```

Hope it make sense.
The goal is to reduce the number of calls to the database, because my interval is always the same (I loop through a date range and make the same call for instance 31 times (if 31 days)

Comment: In other words, you want to get a month's worth of days from the database and then search that result set for each day of the month?

Comment: Yes, but it's not always on day basis. Sometimes it can be on hour basis also the specific day (so it should be dynamic search with some kind of timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily by looping through the rows and testing 'start' and 'end' values.

```
/**
 * @param CI_DB_result instance $result
 * @param array $where with two keys, 'start' and 'end', containing timestamp values, ie. 
 * $where = ['start' => time(), 'end' => strtotime("+1 month"));
 * @return mixed An array of db row objects or NULL if nothing matches
 */
public function get_stored_results($result, $where)
{
    $rows = $result->result();
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        if($row->start >= $where['start'] && $row->end <= $where['end'])
        {
            $matches[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return isset($matches) ? $matches : NULL;
}
```

If you would rather get back an array of row arrays

```
public function get_stored_results($result, $where)
{
    $rows = $result->result_array();
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        if($row['start'] >= $where['start'] && $row['end'] <= $where['end'])
        {
            $matches[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return isset($matches) ? $matches : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Might be it will help you 
In your controller

```
$get_result_info_by_search = $this->Search_model->get_stored_results('start','end',$starttime,$endtime);
```

In your Search Model

```
function get_stored_results($where1,$where2,$value1,$value2)
```

`{

Answer (score 0):

Might be it will work for you in your model try to add this code

```
function get_stored_results($where)
{
   foreach($where as $key => $value)
   {
     $this->db->where($key,$value);
   }
   $result = $this->db->get('bookings');
}
```

Comment: That's not what I need. I need to make the same search inside an array that already have been stored in a variable :-)